# Which attribute do I tag a property with to make the VS2008 designer not save it to the .designer.cs file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, properties, components

If I have an informational property that provides an editor only, in the property inspector, is there an attribute I can tag the property with so that it won't be saved to the .Designer.cs file?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx)